# Odoo loop through a subscription line then set value to field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

Hi am new to both python and Odoo development, I used the web interface for customization before. I was trying to create a class to

1. add a field to sale.subscription Model

`subscription_tier = fields.Char(string='Subscription Tier',readonly=True)`

which is working but the second part is not working
2. loop through subscription line to see if the customer has `silver` or `gold` subscription
then set it to the field `subscription_tier`

```
class subscription_tire_set(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.subscription'

    subscription_tier = fields.Char(string='Subscription Tier',readonly=True)

    @api.depends('recurring_invoice_line_ids.product_id')
    def _compute_release_to_pay(self):
        for n_subscription in self:
            result = None
            for n_subscription_line in n_subscription.recurring_invoice_line_ids:
                if any(n_subscription_line.product_id) == 'gold':
                    
                    result = 'gold'
                    break
                else:
                    result = 'not'

        subscription_tier = result
```

I probably am doing something horribly wrong

also a getting this massge when trying to open any customer in subscription

Something went wrong!
`sale.subscription(10,).subscription_tier`

Thank u for the help in advance.

#### What worked for me:

```
  result = None

  for n_subscription_line in n_subscription.recurring_invoice_line_ids:
                if n_subscription_line.product_id.name == 'gold'
                    result = 'gold'

                    # break

                else:
                    result

  n_subscription.subscription_tier = result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because in the last line you are declaring a variable named `subscription_tier` and set its value to `result`, you should assign the `result` to `subscription_tier` field of the the `n_subscription` record:

```
@api.depends('recurring_invoice_line_ids.product_id')
def _compute_release_to_pay(self):
    for n_subscription in self:
        # Your code
        n_subscription.subscription_tier = result
```

***Edit:***

[any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will return `True` or `False` and your expression `any(n_subscription_line.product_id) == 'gold'` will always be evaluated to `False`

Comment: Thank u for the help I was stuck for hours
I also forgot to add `compute='_compute_release_to_pay'` in the field `subscription_tier`

Comment: just question:
The customer must have one only subscription_tier how can I stop the selection of multiple.
how can I remove the others or should I use onchange on the `n_subscription.recurring_invoice_line_ids`

Comment: Did you try to fill recurring_invoice_line_ids after you made the changes?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply works and sorry for the delay I had uni finals. it worked by after `any` and using `n_subscription_line.product_id.name`

Comment: [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will return `True` or `False` and your expression `any(n_subscription_line.product_id) == 'gold'` will always be evaluated to `False`.

Comment: `result = 'gold'` will never be executed, Check my edit.

Comment: Do you want to check if at least one product attribute is set to `gold`?

Comment: `if any(line.product_id.attr=='gold' for line in n_subscription.recurring_invoice_line_ids)` should work.